# What is the naming convention for Click packages?

Tags: application-development, click-packages

I have made an Ubuntu Touch app and intend to upload it to the [Click app store](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps). What is the naming convention that I should use for naming my Click package?

Answer (score 8):

The package name is usually the name of your application, all in lowercase and using dashes (`-`) instead of spaces.

For example, here are a few of my applications and their package names:

- Weather Desktop became `weather-desktop`.
- Ubuntu Tasks become `ubuntu-tasks`.
- uBible will be `ubible`.

In addition, Click packages also use a namespace which is combined with the package name to form the App ID. The namespace is the developer's domain name reversed, so for example:

- MyAwesomeApps.com would become `com.myawesomeapps`.
- Ubuntu.com would become `com.ubuntu`.

If you don't have your own domain name, you can use the default which is based on your Launchpad user name:

```
com.ubuntu.developer.<lpname>
```

There are a couple of things to note about your developer namespace:

1. Once you've uploaded an app, it cannot be changed. Before you've uploaded an app, if you've made a mistake or would like to change it, you can ask in the `#ubuntu-app-devel` channel to have it changed.
2. You can only use a namespace if you own the domain it represents or if it is the default using your Launchpad user name.

So for example, the App ID for Ubuntu Tasks is

```
com.ubuntu.developer.mdspencer.ubuntu-tasks
```