# Where do I submit applications written for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I've written an application for Ubuntu Touch using the Ubuntu SDK and have packaged it as a click package. Where do I go to submit it to the App Store to make it available for installation in Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DO NOT** click on the My Apps tab at http://developer.ubuntu.com. This is the old application submission method.

Go to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps/new/. This is the new app store for Ubuntu Touch. It should look like this:

[image: Click App Store Submission Form]

You will need to submit your app as a click package, no need for complicated Debian packaging! Once uploaded, your app should be reviewed within a few hours and will then be published and be available for installation on any device running Ubuntu Touch.

Once you've submitted your app, you can track it by going to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps.

***NOTE:*** Currently the Click App Store does not support selling apps. This will be added soon!

For more information about choosing a package name and developer namespace, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/343491/109543).

You can find more information about packaging Ubuntu Touch apps as click packages [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/packaging-click-apps/).