# Why is my Ubuntu Touch app not visible in the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, application-development, click-packages

I submitted a Ubuntu Touch app packaged as a Click package to the Click App Store and it was published a few days ago. It is not in my Ubuntu Software Center, or in the [online version](http://apps.ubuntu.com). I tried a lot of searching, but it did not show up.

Should I resubmit my app? What should I do?

Comment: I recommend asking a new question about how to install the beta app store :)

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/345226/109543) about the different ways to install an Ubuntu Touch app.

Comment: Please don't change the intent of your question after its been answered. If you have a different question, ask it as a new question!

Answer (score 4):

This is because the desktop version of Ubuntu does not support Click packages yet. To view or install your app, currently you must have an Ubuntu Touch device. Also, there is currently no online list of Click apps (remember, the Click App Store is still in Beta).

In the future (by Ubuntu 14.10), Click packages, the new App Store, and Unity 8, along with all the apps written using the Ubuntu SDK, will be available on the desktop as well.

Comment: How do I install the beta click app store?

Comment: @user1628 the click app store is not a program; it is the service that hosts Ubuntu Touch apps. See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/345226/109543) about what the click app store is and how to install Ubuntu Touch apps.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the app that I made with the Ubuntu SDK (Qt etc) onto software centre?