# How do I view or install Ubuntu Touch apps?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, click-packages

Lots of people have started developing Ubuntu Touch apps for the Ubuntu App Showdown and just in general, and have published them in the Click App Store.

What is the Click App Store, and how do I install apps published in it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### What is the Click App Store?

The Click App Store is not an application that runs on your phone, tablet, or computer. Instead, it is the service that hosts Ubuntu Touch apps that have been packaged as Click packages.

### How do I install or view Ubuntu Touch apps?

#### Developer

If you're the developer of an app, you can view your app by going to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps/

[image: Click MyApps site]

#### Website

Currently, there is no equivalent to http://apps.ubuntu.com for viewing Ubuntu Touch apps. I believe this is coming soon, though!

#### Ubuntu Desktop

If you're running the regular, desktop version of Ubuntu, there is no way to view or install Ubuntu Touch apps by default. Currently, the [Ubuntu Software Center does not show Ubuntu Touch apps](https://askubuntu.com/q/345175/109543).

However, I wrote an app using the Ubuntu SDK that lets you view the available apps in the Click App Store:

[image: QML app for viewing the Click App Store]

It is written using the Ubuntu SDK, so that needs to be installed to run it. You can download it from https://github.com/iBeliever/click-appstore, compile and run it as any other Qt app.

Currently, it lets you browse the available apps and view details about them. I'm currently working on a way to install apps on the desktop.

#### Ubuntu Touch

If you're running Ubuntu Touch, you can view and install applications by searching the Applications scope in the Dash.

[image: Available apps]

Comment: *If you're running the regular, desktop version of Ubuntu Touch* What do you mean by this? Is it possible to run Ubuntu Touch as regular desktop Ubuntu, e.g. with Xfce UI and with all available Linux programs?

Comment: @landroni Sorry, that was a typo. I meant the "regular, desktop version of Ubuntu" instead of running Ubuntu Touch on a mobile device.

Answer (score 11):

To **view** Apps please have a look at the following page:

https://uappexplorer.com/apps

there you can browse all available apps, scopes and webapps

if you use the page from within the browser of your phone/tablet you will be redirected to the official app store after clicking on "**install**" where you can install the app

[image]