# Finding installed apps

Tags: ubuntu-touch, appmenu

Where do I see an overview of all installed app on my tablet?

Examples
When I click on an odt file libreoffice is proposed as one possible app to open the file. But if I want to start libreoffice all alone I would not know where to go.

Some apps I installed are only findable via the app store. I have to search for a keyword to find the app wich is marked installed next to other apps. This is not really handy for using apps..

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/345226/how-do-i-view-or-install-ubuntu-touch-apps

Comment: This question does not appear to be a duplicate of the one you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu Touch on your tablet, all installed apps are available in the Dash (you may have to tap on the "Show all") or the Desktop Apps scope (you may have to swipe left to bring it up).

Comment: I don't see where to tick "show all". When swiping left I get to the apps I marked with a star in the manager..