# Is PPA still the only way to publish free open source app for Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: software-center, application-development, ppa

There is a lot of contradicting information about publishing for Desktop. Some sources say that from 14.10 onwards Click packages also for Desktop can be submitted to USC. Other sources say that Click packages are only for Touch. And then there are Snappy packages.

There are bugs open about submitting free open source apps to USC being impossible (see e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-portal/+bug/1409749). I'm *SO* confused right now. Is PPA still the only way to publish free open source app for Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

> Is PPA still the only way to publish free open source app for Ubuntu Desktop?

Yes, well if you do not want to go through the validation process Canonical enforces. And PPA is a lot easier if you already have a .DEB.

[Click](https://click.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ([What are Click packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337969/what-are-click-packages)) and [Snappy](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/) are basically the same (where Snappy is an improved version of Click intended for server side installation and Click is intended for client side installation). Both are intended for mobile phones and as a side effect usable on the desktop.

We will turn from .DEB installers since the 15.10 release will have [Snappy installation](https://plus.google.com/+WillCooke/posts/AxfoU3N1Ezo). So maybe that will also see the end of PPAs.

Comment: According to bug 1409749 there's no validation process. It's just impossible to submit free open source apps to USC.

Comment: That is undecided and unconfirmed ;)

Comment: Well, I tried it and that's how it goes.

Comment: Also @user205301 I can confirm the bug is a fact, I tried several times, no luck since 2012.

Comment: The focus probably got shifted to snappy. The google+ page seems to indicate it.

Comment: I'm happy to eventually get rid of DEBs and PPAs, but not being able to submit open source apps since 2012 is beyond pathetic :)