# How does Click/Snappy solve dependency issues?

Tags: dependencies, packaging, ubuntu-core, click-packages, snap

There is a bit of confusion surrounding click and snappy.

For one, I understand that there are certain packages that are not allowed to be shared due to app-armor. For example, if I write a Qt application that executes a python script, app armor will prevent me from using the installed python interpreter on my own system. My program however does depend on a python interpreter.

How would Click/Snappy solve this and other dependency issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a snap package, you can simply have two parts: one being your Qt app, the second one being the python script. Parts in snaps are handled by plugins and they make sure everything gets installed in the right place and have what they need. For example could your Qt app be built using the `cmake` plugin and your python script using the `python3` plugin.

In short: you bundle what you need and what's not provided by the OS. This may change and be expanded in the future.

Find out more here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/snappy/build-apps/